# Angular não funciona pelo browser do celular

Tags: angular

Estou tentando salvar um formulário pelo browser do celular (Chrome e Opera), porém, após preencher os dados e pedir para salvar nada acontece, o formulário não é submetido, a requisição não chega nem no backend e não tenho nenhuma validação no formulário.
O botão Cancelar funciona, me redireciona para uma outra tela "/lista", onde deveria exibir uma tabela com os cadastros feito, mas a tabela é  exibida sem nenhuma informação.

Pelo desktop está tudo funcionando, tanto o cadastro quanto a listagem dos que foram cadastrado.

Alguém sabe me dizer porque isso acontece?
Estou utilizando Angular 7.1.4

Para o submit do formulário já tentei usar button e input, mas nenhum dos dois funcionou, e nem colocando (click)="onSubmit()" direto no botão deu certo.

Template.

```
<form [formGroup]="formPessoa" 
      (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >

 <div class="form-group">
<label for="nome">Nome</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
      name="name" id="nome" 
formControlName="nome">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="nome">CPF</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control"name="cpf" id="cpf" formControlName="cpf">
</div>

 .
 . restante do formulário
 .

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary 
mt-4" value="Salvar"  >Salvar</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn- 
 secondary mt-4 ml-2" 
(click)="goToList()">Cancelar</button>
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: tentou emular mobile pelo navegador do computador? isso é bem estranho, deveria funcionar normal.

Comment: Emerson, usei um simulador pelo computador e funcionou normal... mas pelo celular continua não funcionando, nem pelo navegador nativo, já testei em dois celulares e em um Ipad

Comment: o que posso fazer é tentar reproduzir aqui e testar no meu celular e tentar encontrar o erro/solução